# Python - Return true if strings found in nested list

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

My goal is to return True/False if I am able to detect two items within a nested list.

E.g.

```py
list1 = [['1', 'sjndnjd3', 'MSG1'], ['2', 'jdakb2', 'MSG1'], ['1', 'kbadkjh', 'MSG2']]
```

I want to iterate over this list to confirm if I can find '1' & 'MSG1' within a nested list. Important to note I only want this to return true if both items are found and if they're found within the same nested list.

I've tried various combinations of the below however I cannot get it quite right.

```py
all(x in e for e in list1 for x in ['1', 'MSG1'])
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to match two items within same group or is matching in different group is also required?

Comment: In the above instance, both '1' and 'MSG1' need to be within the same nested list. E.g. only list1[0] should match. In the event that list1 only contained list1[1] & list1[2], this should return false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
contains = any([True for sublist in list1 if "1" in sublist and "MSG1" in sublist])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`set.issubset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.issubset):

```
any(True for sub_list in list1 if {'1', 'MSG1'}.issubset(set(sub_list)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply `all` to each test of `1` and `MSG` being in `list1`, so you need to rewrite your list comprehension as

```
found = [all(x in e for x in ['1', 'MSG1']) for e in list1]
# [True, False, False]
```

You can then test for any of those values being true:

```
any(found)
# True
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function as follows, using `sum` and list's `count` method:

```
def str_in_nested(list_, string_1, string_2):
    return sum(sub_list.count(string_1) and sub_list.count(string_2) for sub_list in list_) > 0
```

Applying this function to you current case:

```
>>> list1 = [['1', 'sjndnjd3', 'MSG1'], ['2', 'jdakb2', 'MSG1'], ['1', 'kbadkjh', 'MSG2']]
>>> str_in_nested(list1, '1', 'MSG1')
True
```

Answer (score 0):

It's:

```
any(all(item in sublist for item in ['1', 'MSG1']) for sublist in list1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try...

```
for item in list1:
    all(i in item for i in sub)
```