# returning true if numbers are duplicated in a list

Tags: python-3.x

Here's my code.  I've seen many sophisticated codes I don't understand so I'm trying to use the basics I've learned.

```
def containsDuplicate(nums):
    table = set()
for num in nums:
    if num not in table:
        table.addend(num)
    else:
        return TRUE
return FALSE
```

It messes up in the return line.  It says it's outside the function

Comment: Your indentation is messed up. It matters in Python.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SOF! did you try to debug your code? I suggest reading this for future questions you might have: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - Return true if strings found in nested list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60680100/python-return-true-if-strings-found-in-nested-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you already understand indentation stuffs from the first answer,let me show you another way of doing the same task in python:

```py
def checkIfDuplicates(nums):
    if len(nums) == len(set(nums)):
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

Comment: Or just `return len(nums) != len(set(nums))`.

Comment: OP's function name `containsDuplicate` is pretty good in that it already suggests that in case of duplicates it will return `True`. With `checkIfDuplicates` I think it's not so obvious, i.e. it doesn't seem unreasonable that in case of duplicates the "check" would return `False`, because "we didn't pass the check" (duplicates are usually a bad thing).

Answer (score 2):

1. Your indentation is incorrect.
2. It has to be `True` and `False`, not `TRUE`and `FALSE`.
3. The method `set.addend()` does not exist. You probably meant `set.add()`.

It should look like this:

```
def containsDuplicate(nums):
    table = set()
    for num in nums:
        if not num in table:
            table.add(num)
        else:
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: Thank you for such quick help.  I made all the changes, but as far as indentation, I've tried moving it, but to no avail.  Of course I'll continue maybe by moving it one space at a time until it accepts?

Comment: I got it!  It was the first for that was misplaced.  You guys rock!  thanks a bunch

Comment: @JasonAndrews You are welcome. Please consider *accepting* my answer.